# JPEG2000 viewer and support on Android

Tags: android, viewer, jpeg2000

I am looking for JPEG 2000 (jp2,jpx) support on Android.
I checked up various google and non Google groups, but they seems to be of not much help.
Could anyone please guide.
If anyone knows of a JPEG2000 viewer for Android, please share.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I've used [jj2000](http://code.google.com/p/jj2000/) on Android.

Comment: Some notes for people thinking about going this way: JJ2000 includes a bunch of AWT code, which can be hacked out to run on Android.  However, it decodes the whole image into memory at the full size - even if you decode to a smaller size - for me, this was enough to scuttle it, as it wanted to allocate more than my VM budget on the images that I am interested in.  I do have a half-baked Android port if anyone wants it, though.